# Is it possible to set the value of a config file to reflect chosen windows installer path?

Tags: c#, configuration, installation, windows-installer

I have a program that I am going to deploy via a Windows installer. The program outputs files to a location specified in a app.config file.

Is it possible to change the value of the config file to the path selected during the install?

So the process would be as follows.

1. User runs windows installer
2. User selects path to install program
3. Output variable in app.config changed to location of install
4. User can then edit the config file to change output variable if they wish to change the output path.

**Update:** Ok so now I know how to create a custom install process as per this link:
[Configure App.config Application Settings During MSI Install](http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/)

This is fine if you want to just use the standard set of controls but I would like a file chooser for them to be able to choose the output path, how can I do this?

Ok I figured out what I needed to do... Heres the answer...

Add an installer class to the project you want to install as per instructions in the link.

Then override the install method in that class as follows to read the path that that user inputs as install directory..

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {

            base.Install(stateSaver);

            string targetDirectory = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];

            string exePath = string.Format("{0}BarcodeScanner.exe", targetDirectory);

            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);

            config.AppSettings.Settings["ILPrintExportPath"].Value = targetDirectory;


            config.Save();

        }
```

Then follow the other stages in the above link :)

As Joe said I will have to either ensure the users run the app as an administrator or install outside the program files directory so its not a perfect solution but it does what I need it to do.

Comment: I can help you with 1 to 3 if you use WiX: http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2005/10/13/427398.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article [Configure App.config Application Settings During MSI Install](http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/) which shows how to do this using a C# custom action which uses the standard .Net `ConfigurationManager` class to open and update the app.config file.

Comment: this is great thanks... although having looked at it I would like to be able to add a file chooser control instead of just a text box. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) to get the directory the EXE is running from? I don't see any need to add a configuration setting -- it's not like this is something you want to be user-configurable after your app is installed.

```
var exePath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var exeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
```

Comment: It is something I want to be user configurable. I need them to be able to change the programs output, but have it output to the install location unless changed.

Comment: Agree with Joe. I'd set up your program output files relative to the Executing assembly's path. If you want it to be some relative path from this, have your app.config include a setting for a path relative to the installed location.

Comment: As I said I said there is no rigid rules on where the output directory should be and will be different for each user.

Comment: Not sure I follow. App.config settings can be specified as Application scope (all users) or User scope (each user gets a unique copy and can be set by your program).

Comment: Dude, your program *can't* write to its own install directory (unless the user right-clicks on it and selects "Run as administrator", but that should **not** be your normal mode of operation). Why on earth would you want a read-only directory as your default output location?

Comment: This program is going to be distributed to a number of people. The output directory for each of those people will be different.
Why cant the program create a file in the installation directory?Is there a block on that?

Comment: Of course. The Program Files directory is read-only unless you do "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

If you want that path to be by default same as install directory, you may just use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` if there is no entry in your config. But then, there will be no possibility to set other path during install (not sure if you wanted that).

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is the working directory, not the install directory. They may be the same, depending on how you run the program, but often they are not.